# Java TCP Socket receiving bytes with specified length

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am trying to first read 4 bytes(int) specifying the size of the message and then read the remaining bytes based on the byte count. I am using the following code to accomplish this:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(
                        mClientSocket.getInputStream());

// read the message length
int len = dis.readInt();

Log.i(TAG, "Reading bytes of length:" + len);

// read the message data
byte[] data = new byte[len];
if (len > 0) {
    dis.readFully(data);
} else {
    return "";
}
return new String(data);
```

Is there a better/efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Provided you are going with blocking I/O, I think it's pretty efficient as it is, especially if you have to interact with non-Java code.  The only smell here is calling a `String` constructor without specifying correct encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF%28%29) of readUTF:

> First, **two bytes are read and used to construct an unsigned *16-bit***
>   **integer** in exactly the manner of the readUnsignedShort method . This
>   integer value is called the UTF length **and specifies the number of
>   additional bytes to be read**. These bytes are then converted to
>   characters by considering them in groups. The length of each group is
>   computed from the value of the first byte of the group. The byte
>   following a group, if any, is the first byte of the next group.

The only problem with this is that your protocol seems to only send 4 bytes for the payload length. Perhaps you can do a similar method but increase the size of length sentinel read to 4 bytes/32-bits.

Also, I see that you are just doing new String(bytes) which works fine as long as the encoding of the data is the same as "the platform's default charset." See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%29) So it would be much safer to just ensure that you are encoding it correctly(e.g. if you know that the sender sends it as UTF-8 then do new String(bytes,"UTF-8") instead).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                     mClientSocket.getInputStream()));

return dis.readUTF();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I need to read specified number of bytes. Not the entire message. dis.readUTF() reads everything in the stream right?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` like this

```
byte[] data = new byte[len];
dis.read(data,0,len);
```